# AES encrypting in Java vs .NET

Tags: java, c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have a Java code that encrypts data using AES. Here is a snippet encoding a simple string

```
String key="MySecretKeyABCDE";
SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
byte[] ivbytes = new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivbytes);//need IV in CBC mode

Cipher m_enc_cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
m_enc_cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey, iv);

String content ="Hello";
byte[] contentBArr = content.getBytes();
byte[] block = new byte[4080];
System.arraycopy(contentBArr,0,block,0,contentBArr.length);
byte[] res = m_enc_cipher.doFinal(block,0,block.length);
```

I need to create an equivalent .NET code. I have written this

```
var csp = new RijndaelManaged
{
    Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
    Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,                
    Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MySecretKeyABCDE"),
    IV = new byte[] {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15}
 };

 var e = csp.CreateEncryptor();
 var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello");
 var block = new byte[4080];
 Array.Copy(content,block,content.Length);
 var res = e.TransformFinalBlock(block,0,block.Length);
```

When I compare the res variable they are different in the Java version and in the .NET version. I know Java uses unsigned bytes, but the results are really different, not only "shifted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason that you use different IVs?

You use the IV

```
new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
```

in Java whereas you use the IV

```
new byte[] {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15}
```

in C#.

In Java you use decimal numbers and in C# hex numbers which translate to

```
new byte[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21}
```

in decimal notation.

If you use different IVs you will get different cipher texts.